# In the context of deep-sea exploration, what is the pronunciation of 蛤 (gé​ vs. há​)?

Tags: pronunciation, word

> 潜水到几千米深海底的科学家发现了一个繁殖生命的场所，那里的生物长相古怪，​**蛤**，蚌，蟹，贝壳，红冠蠕虫等等，什么都有。
> <sub>HSK6 Standard Course 6上, chapter 19.</sub>

I'm not too sure about how to pronounce 蛤 above:

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%9B%A4): 蛤 (gé​) clam; (há​) frog / toad

The HSK6 textbook comes with a recording where it's pronounced gé​, and the previous page shows a photo of a 蛤蜊 (gé​lí​) = "clam", including the pinyin.  However, Chinese Zero to Hero ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6cYH.png)) pronounces it há​ in both the audio and the pinyin, which suggests this might be an acceptable alternative.  Indeed, [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zj1WNsV7T7o&t=48s) says gé but writes há​.

**Question**: In the context of deep-sea exploration, what is the pronunciation of 蛤?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

蛤(gé) is correct.
蛤蟆(há ma) 蛤only pronounced há when it means toad.
蛤is pronounced (gé) when it refers to shell creature in deep ocean.
There should be no toads in the deep sea.蛤，蚌，蟹，贝壳，红冠蠕虫 are all mollusca.
so in this context, 蛤means 蛤蜊(gé​lí​).

Comment: Many native speakers mispronounce this character, but the correct pronunciation is gé​lí​,